# Repeating a block of text until it fills a page

Tags: macros, vertical-alignment, loops

Might I please have some help with writing a loop that repeats a block of text as many times as there is remaining space for it on the page?

I would like to produce an notebook in TeX which is divided into a number of sections. Each section would start with some printed records (taken from an existing database) followed by some space to hand-write in new entries.

The space for handwritten records is generated by something along the following lines:

```
\noindent Type of Widget: \dotfill \break
Observations: \dotfill \break
\null\dotfill
```

The problem I have is that of vertical alignment: I want each section to start at the top of a new page, followed by the printed records and then enough blocks for handwritten notes to fill up the remaining vertical space on that page. Something like this:

---

**Section: Special Widgets**

*Type of Widget:* ABC123

*Observations:* Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id orci nunc, sed sollicitudin lectus.

*Type of Widget:* CDE123

*Observations:* Etiam lacus sem, pharetra vel eleifend ac, elementum at leo. Ut pulvinar, lorem sit amet feugiat hendrerit, sapien justo accumsan eros, eleifend consectetur nisl urna at nibh.

*Type of Widget:* ...........

*Observations*: ...................................................................................................

............................................................................................................................

*Type of Widget:* ...........

*Observations*: ...................................................................................................

............................................................................................................................

---

Since the length of the records can vary, I therefore need to run a loop which does something like the following (in eplain pseudo code):

```
\for
    \noindent Type of Widget: \dotfill \break
    Observations: \dotfill \break
    \null\dotfill
\if **test to see if there is enough vspace to repeat block**
\repeat
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how to write a test for "is there enough space left on the page to print this block of text?". I presume I would start by making a \vbox the size of the block and then see if it will fit onto the current page but I can't work out how to make that work.

I hope this is clear enough. If not, please let me know.

Thanks.

-Jacob

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a place to use vertical leaders. Here is a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newsavebox\widgetbox
\begin{document}
\setbox\widgetbox\vbox
  {\vspace*{6pt}\noindent Type of Widget: \dotfill \break
  Observations: \dotfill \break
  \null\dotfill\par}

\lipsum[1]

\cleaders\copy\widgetbox\vskip0pt plus 1fill
\end{document}
```

With `\cleaders` the boxes will be put right on top of each other, with space added on top and bottom to fill the page. Use `\xleaders` instead to have the extra space between the boxes.

You could also use `\leaders`, which should place these boxes in the same position on every page. But then you need to pay attention to dimensions. Ideally, the page height should be a whole multiple of the height of your `\widgetbox`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I should have guessed there would be a TeX primitive which would do this for me!

Answer (score 0):

Harald's answer did need to be translated into plain TeX for my purposes. My first effort is the following which seems to work, except that (for reasons I don't quite yet understand), I need to add an extra page following the \cleaders and \eject:

```
\setbox0=\vbox{\noindent Type of Widget: \dotfill \break
  Observations: \dotfill \break
  \null\dotfill\break
  }

Lorem ipsum dolor etc.

\cleaders\box0\vfill

\eject

Another Page

\bye
```

Comment: `\bye` does its own `\vfill`, which then gets one half of the remaining space on the last page. If you replace your own `\vfill` with `\vskip 0pt plus 1filll` (the triple l is not a misprint), you get what you expect. (Or you can replace the final `\bye` with `\supereject\end`.) Also, you need to use `\copy`, not `\box`, or your box register is emptied after the first use.

Comment: Oh, and `\box0` is not likely to survive very long anyhow. For plain TeX, just replace `\newsavebox` by `\newbox`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; particularly of what was happening with \bye. That's very helpful.