# Overlapping material

Tags: tex-core

In [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6608/repeating-a-block-of-text-until-it-fills-a-page/6611#6611), Harald showed how to make vertical leaders. Armed with this knowledge, I set sail to answer another question, but as I've tried to put such leaders into a page with other material as well, the leaderfill always takes up the whole page.

Is there a general way to typeset something onto a page, which then would be handled by TeX as if nothing had been typeset at all (i.e., it wouldn't take any kind of space away from other material)?

Example:

```
\newbox\needlebox\setbox\needlebox=\vbox{\hsize=2em$\cdot$}
\def\needlefill{\cleaders\copy\needlebox\vskip0pt plus 1fill}
\llap{\hbox to 2em{\vbox to\vsize{\hsize=2em\needlefill}}} Blah
\bye
```

(The "Blah" goes to second page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\llap` is the right direction, but you still need a vertical version of it:

```
\newbox\needlebox\setbox\needlebox=\vbox{\hsize=2em$\cdot$}
\def\needlefill{\cleaders\copy\needlebox\vskip0pt plus 1fill}
\llap{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox to 2em{\vbox to\vsize{\hsize=2em\needlefill}}\vss}} Blah
\bye
```

See also [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/tree/browse_frm/thread/6e54b81e6bfd62e5/d3ed9fd54272bef2?rnum=1&q=Vertical+versions+of+%5Cllap+and+%5Crlap%3A+%5Ctlap+and+%5Cblap&_done=%2Fgroup%2Fcomp.text.tex%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fthread%2F6e54b81e6bfd62e5%2Fd3ed9fd54272bef2%3Flnk%3Dgst%26q%3DVertical%2Bversions%2Bof%2B%255Cllap%2Band%2B%255Crlap%253A%2B%255Ctlap%2Band%2B%255Cblap%26#doc_d3ed9fd54272bef2) on c.t.t I started about `\blap` and `\tlap` macros.

Answer (score 2):

(not tested)

a box in vertical mode gets set and stays in vertical mode.  you need to get
out of vertical mode.

precede the `\llap` by `\leavevmode` to put you into horizontal mode.

you may also want to give \vbox the height of a line of text to avoid having
it line up at the bottom.  `\vbox to Npt{...}` where N = the height of the first
line; the height of `\mathstrut` is probably a good value.