# How to specify a very long page?

Tags: geometry, paper-size

I want a long page length, and even though the PDF output shows the long page, I can only get text placed on a portion of it.  I used code from [this question about repeating a long block of text until it fills a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6608/repeating-a-block-of-text-until-it-fills-a-page), and added the geometry package along with the adjustments for the width and height that I want. But, this does not fill up the page as I want. This is not a problem with the code in the above example, as I am seeing similar behavior in my own files: the page looks long, but has a lot of blank space and things get moved to the next page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=10px,right=10px,top=10px,bottom=10px]{geometry}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.0in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{33.0in}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newsavebox\widgetbox
\begin{document}

\setbox\widgetbox\vbox
  {\vspace*{6pt}\noindent Type of Widget: \dotfill \break
  Observations: \dotfill \break
  \null\dotfill\par}

\lipsum[1]

\cleaders\copy\widgetbox\vskip0pt plus 1fill
\end{document}
```

Also, any idea why the lipsum text is getting cut of on the right? I would have though that LaTeX would have adjusted for the narrower text?

Comment: Follow up Questions: [How define a fixed width page, but length > some minimum length, but only as long as needed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19672/how-define-a-fixed-width-page-but-length-some-minimum-length-but-only-as-lon), and [Automate Fixed Width Page, length > some minimum length, but only as long as needed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/automate-fixed-width-page-length-some-minimum-length-but-only-as-long-as-nee).

Comment: Related Question: [How do I create a PDF document whose height exactly matches the contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459459/4301).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve both problems by using the `paperwidth` and `paperheight` options `geometry` provides instead of setting the values "manually" with `\setlength`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=10px,right=10px,top=10px,bottom=10px,paperwidth=8in,paperheight=33in]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newsavebox\widgetbox
\begin{document}

\setbox\widgetbox\vbox
  {\vspace*{6pt}\noindent Type of Widget: \dotfill \break
  Observations: \dotfill \break
  \null\dotfill\par}

\lipsum[1]

\cleaders\copy\widgetbox\vskip0pt plus 1fill
\end{document}
```

Comment: @diabonas: Why do you use the `px` unit? It is specific to pdftex and meant for uning it with images

Comment: @Herbert I used the same specifications the OP provided in his question.

Comment: @diabonas: Ah sorry, didn't realized that ... then it is a comment to Peter