# Automate Fixed Width Page, length > some minimum length, but only as long as needed

Tags: margins, geometry

I am trying to automate the solution proposed by egreg to [How define a fixed width page, but length > some minimum length, but only as long as needed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19672/how-define-a-fixed-width-page-but-length-some-minimum-length-but-only-as-long/19721#19721) by hooking into `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

So, egreg's solution works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\MinimumPaperHeight{12cm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=\MinimumPaperHeight,paperheight=\maxdimen,margin=1cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setbox0=\vbox{
\lipsum[1-6]
}
\dimen0=\dp0
\pdfpageheight=\dimexpr\ht0+2cm\relax
\ifdim\pdfpageheight<\MinimumPaperHeight \pdfpageheight=\MinimumPaperHeight \fi
\unvbox0\kern-\dimen0
\end{document}
```

But can't seem to get this to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\MinimumPaperHeight{12cm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=\MinimumPaperHeight,paperheight=\maxdimen,margin=1cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{MyBox}{
    \setbox0=\vbox{\BODY}%
}{%
    \dimen0=\dp0%
    \pdfpageheight=\dimexpr\ht0+2cm\relax%
    \ifdim\pdfpageheight<\MinimumPaperHeight \pdfpageheight=\MinimumPaperHeight \fi%
    \unvbox0\kern-\dimen0%
}

\AtBeginDocument{\begin{MyBox}}
\AtEndDocument{\end{MyBox}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Hooking into `\AtBeginDocument` is per this solution on [How to automatically add text immediately after \begin{document}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14135/how-to-automatically-add-text-immediately-after-begindocument).

Comment: Related Question: [What's the absolute largest paper size permissible with pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420/whats-the-absolute-largest-paper-size-permissible-with-pdflatex).

Comment: Related Question: [How do I create a PDF document whose height exactly matches the contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459459/4301).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can't work, because `\begin{MyBox}` needs to *see* `\end{MyBox}`, but it doesn't because the document ends before the tokens are actually present: the contents of an environment defined with `\NewEnviron` is not expanded until it's processed with the expansion of `\BODY`.

One solution is to hook directly into `\document` and `\enddocument`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup
  \preto\enddocument{\egroup
    \dimen0=\dp0
    \pdfpageheight=\dimexpr\ht0+2cm\relax
    \ifdim\pdfpageheight<\MinimumPaperHeight
      \pdfpageheight=\MinimumPaperHeight
    \fi
    \unvbox0\kern-\dimen0 }
}
```

(Not heavily tested, sorry.)

Comment: This works great. But, if using the `standalone` package, need to use `[preview=false]` option.

Comment: This works great, except I can't figure out how to get a footer back in the pdf (using KOMA classes). It seems the footer is arranged based on the original page height (`\maxdimen`) then cropped off when the document ends. Should I ask another question about this or can you think of an easy way to integrate it as a fix in this solution?

Comment: @Caleb My first attempt would be to add the footer just before `\egroup` (maybe as a prebuilt box). If you don't succeed, please ask a new question.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for me in overleaf. It makes each page giant, but the contents of each page appear to be unchanged. So I have the same pages as before, only each page is giant..

Comment: @HughPerkins sorry, but this hacks is outdated and wii definitely break with current LaTeX

Comment: Alright. Thoughts on how to do this in recent latex, overleaf, etc?