# How do I create a PDF document whose height exactly matches the contents?

Tags: pdf, include, page

I have a document that is about 1/3 to 1/2 page long. I want to compile it to a PDF document. That PDF document will be included in another document, so I want it to be short - it should contain only the contents of the document, without white space below it. How can I do this?

Comment: Related Question: [Automate Fixed Width Page, length > some minimum length, but only as long as needed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27041/4301).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the `standalone` class in combination with a minipage of the same width as the text in your main document:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{345pt}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

To find out what the width of the text in your main document is, the `showdim` package offers the `\tenthpt` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showdim}

\begin{document}

\tenthpt{\textwidth}

\lipsum[2]

\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(the vertical space between the text and the image might need a bit of adjustment)

Answer (score 10):

Use `pdfcrop`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\pagestyle{empty} % no page ornaments

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Save this as `shortdoc.tex` and run

```
pdflatex shortdoc
pdfcrop shortdoc
```

This will produce `shortdoc-crop.pdf`, that you can include with `\includegraphics`.