# vertical dotfill

Tags: rules

**How can I make vertical dotfill?**

In other words, I need vertical (dashed) line  which will fill all available vertical space.

(I tried to make it via rules, but not successfully.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Do you mean something like: `\def\vrulefill{\leaders\hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\vfill }`

Comment: Here is an earlier answer to vertical leaders: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6611/1410

Answer (score 8):

You can use leaders:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

\newcommand{\dotvfill}{%
  \par\leaders\hbox{$\cdot$}\vfill}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\dotvfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is there an empty pair of brackets after `[1]`?

Comment: @Sigur A remainder of an earlier try. Fixed.