# What is the Latex code for making many vertical dots in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I need them going all the way down but the **colon** only gives me 2 dots and if I put another **colon** on the next line, a gap appears between them. Basically need to show a table continuation with ...... but vertically.

Comment: Are you looking for `\vdots`?

Comment: `\vdots` makes 3 of them. I don't think there exists a `\vdotfill` command, as there is a `\hdotfill`.

Comment: yes \vdots works but how do I get more than 3 dots?

Comment: How about adding the command several times. If it doesnt work, put `\mbox{}` in between.

Comment: Does this help:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106354/vertical-dotfill

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this can help. Otherwise you probably need to elaborate a bit on the question formulation, it is not really clear how the dots should be used.

The idea is to use `\dotfill` to get a (horizontal) line of dots of a certain *length*. Then use `\rotatebox` to turn it vertically. The `\raisebox` lifts it `1em` over the baseline. When using it `\strut\rlap{\rule{5em}{0.1pt}}` prints a thin line along the baseline. To get a specific number of dots try to trim the length of line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\longvdots[1]{\raisebox{1em}{\rotatebox{-90}{\hbox to #1 {\dotfill}}}}
\begin{document}
\strut\rlap{\rule{5em}{0.1pt}} a \longvdots{3em} b
\end{document}
```

[image]